How to check some validation in a dataframe and logging the errors in a CSV file in a format?
Using the data set below as below
Df=
    Roll.  Marks.  Grade City
   0  123.  40      C.    Kol
   1. 476   80.     B.    Bhu
   2  789   20      D.    Che
   3. NaN.  90.     A.    Kol
   4. NaN.  70.     A.    Che

I need to do checks like any roll is NaN/null and if any marks is below 35.
If there is any such find need to log the error in a CSV file I the below format.
> Timestamp.       Error details
> Current date.   Check failed at row no.3,column Roll. Error value:Nan
> Current date.   Check failed at row no.2,column Marks. Error value:20

I have tried checks with isna.any() and if condition but after the check using CSV writer to create and write log
roll=df['roll'].isna().any()
if roll:
  print("Roll is missing")
  with open('log.csv','w',newline='') as log:
    writer=csv.writer(log)
    writer.writerow([df].columns)
    for v in df.to_numpy():
      writer.writerow(v)

but its not getting in the said format. Using python 3.6
Pls help

This will need some Python code to create a new dataframe with the desired format or creating the CSV directly without using pandas. If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

roll=df['roll'].isna().any()
if roll:
print("Roll is missing")
with open('log.csv','w',newline='') as log:
writer=csv.writer(log)
writer.writerow([df].columns)
for v in df.to_numpy():
writer.writerow(v)

You can create a DataFrame using a dictionary of check functions, stack and items:
checks = {'Roll': lambda s: s.isna(), 'Marks': lambda s: s.lt(35)}

m = df.apply(checks).stack()

out = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': pd.Timestamp('today').normalize(),
                    'Error details': [
                        f'Check failed at row no.{row}, column {col}. Error value: {val}'
                         for (row, col), val in df[list(checks)].stack(dropna=False)[m].items()
                    ]})

Output:
   Timestamp                                              Error details
0 2024-04-22  Check failed at row no.2, column Marks. Error value: 20.0
1 2024-04-22    Check failed at row no.3, column Roll. Error value: nan
2 2024-04-22    Check failed at row no.4, column Roll. Error value: nan

